# IIS 7.5 finds the local web site but can't load it

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7

I am having this strange problem:
I have just developed a WCF service (on VS2008) and created a website (ASP.net) to use that service. When I launch the website from VS2008, it works fine and I get the "You have created a service method", but if I try to open that service using IIS then it is not able to load the website at all. I get a message that "website found, waiting for reply", but the browser is not able to load the service at all.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to Host WCF Service in IIS

Comment: Install Fiddler so you can see a detailed output as to what is actually happening. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: @DSW: I have done everything mentioned in that, in fact, I followed this tutorial verbatim (http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Hosting-WCF-Services-in-IIS/) -- however, as you will at the end of the tutorial, when they click on "View on Browser" from IIS - the website loads immediately, my website is not loading at all, the browser keeps waiting for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was problem with my IIS 7.5, in that ASP.NET was not registered for IIS. The following article was helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

I used aspnet_"regiis -i" command and the websites started loading. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

A few troubleshooting items

1. Make sure in inetmgr under **Web Services Extension** that the required frameworks are unblocked.
2. Enable [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to watch the messages
3. Enable exception details in faults
4. Make sure you are running the website under correct framework (under website properties)
5. In web.config, clear and add handler *svc-Integrated-4.0*